# how to set value in List with out using foreach loop

Tags: linq, linq-expressions

I am having two lists and filter based on a group of values.

```
 var UserIdList = response.Users.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

 var filteredRecords = 
(from o in om.Organizations join u in om.Users on o.Id equals u.OrganizationId where UserIdList.Contains(u.Id)    
                 select new { Enabled = o.Enabled, Id = u.Id }).ToList();
```

Now i want to set `'Exists'` property in '`response.Users`' to true if '`Id`'  exists in `filteredRecords`.

Please let me know how can I set value with out using `foreach` loop.
 I have tried with

```
 response.Users.Where(x => x.Exists = (filteredRecords .Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))).ToList();
```

but could not succeed as it is giving only filter results.
I want full records which are matched and which are not

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: What is a nature of response.Users, om.Organizations, and om.Users. Are they all simple IEnumerable (i.e. in memory collections) or all/some of them IQueryable (db queries).

Comment: I have tired with response.Users.Where(x => x.Exists = (filteredRecords .Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))).ToList(); But able to get only the matched records,but i want to have all the records in response.

Comment: I cannot use foreach as number of records are more

Comment: In such case you can not use ToList in a first place, while foreach can deal with large number of records quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Linq doesn't really support update scenarios as it's for querying data.

For lists however there's a ForEach extension method:

```
UserList
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(item=> item.Exists = filteredRecords.Any(f=> f.Id == item.Id));
```

Is this clearer to read and easier to understand than a foreach loop...

**Edit (after question updates)**

```
// You can't use this... it won't even compile, 
// x.Exists = ... is an assignment not a condition
response.Users.Where(x => x.Exists = (filteredRecords .Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))).ToList();
```

What you want to do is to work with a subset of users and update the values.

```
response
  .Users
  .Where(x=> filteredRecords.Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))
  .ToList() // This materialises your IEnumerable/IQueryable to allow the ForEach extension method
  .ForEach(x => x.Exists = true);
```

you could of course use:

```
var usersToEnable = response.Users.Where(x=> filteredRecords.Any(z => z.Id == x.Id);
foreach(var user in usersToEnable)
  user.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a direct response to:

> Please let me know how can I set value with out using foreach loop. I have tried with
>
> ```
>  response.Users.Where(x => x.Exists = (filteredRecords .Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))).ToList(); but could not succeed as it is giving only
> ```
>
> filter results. I want full records which are matched and which are
>   not

What you've done there is selected a collection of response user items you wish to have `Exists` set to true.

Now you need to set that bool in this filtered collection, and then return the *full* `response` collection afterwards, instead of returning the filtered collection.

I think this is where you're getting confused.